# Chef - access new_resource from library

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

Is there a way I can access `new_resource` attributes from inside a Chef library (in `libraries/default.rb`) ?

My current solution is:

In `libraries/default.rb`

```
module Libraries
    def init(resource)
       @@server_name = resource.server_name
       @@server_type = resource.server_type
       @@script      = get_script_path
       ...
    end
    def get_script_path
       if @@server_type == 'admin'
          script = 'admin_cntl.sh'
          path   = '/admin_server/bin'
       elsif @@server_type == 'managed'
          script = 'managed_cntl.sh'
          path   = '/managed_server/bin'
       end
       ::File.join(path, script)
    end
end
```

In `providers/default.rb`

```
include Libraries

action :start do 
   init(new_resource)
   execute 'my_script' do 
      command "./#{@@script} start"
   end
end

action :remove do 
   init(new_resource)
   execute 'my_script' do 
      command "./#{@@script} stop"
   end
end
```

I think this is unnecessary overhead but I couldn't come up with a better solution.

Is there a better way ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It feels like some context is missing.

Comment: I need to compute variables from ```new_resource``` 's attributes.
Some computation are heavy and check on the values of different attributes and need to be in the library, not in the provider. 

Then I access the computed variables from the provider directly.

Comment: I edited my question to show one use-case. I know I could pass ```new_resource``` attributes directly to ```get_script_path``` but it would be redundant in different ```actions```, especially knowing the real code has tons of library functions using these attributes. I find this much cleaner, but still I'd like to get rid of ```init``` function and access those directly in ```Libraries``` module. I also know that libraries are executed before any other things in  Chef, but I'm just asking if that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a normal mixin:

```
# libraries/default.rb
module MyLibrary
  def script_path
    case new_resource.server_type
    when 'admin'
      '/admin_server/bin/admin_cntl.sh'
    when 'managed'
      '/managed_server/bin/managed_cntl.sh'
    end
  end
end

# providers/default.rb
include MyLibrary

action :start do 
   execute 'my_script' do 
      command "./#{script_path} start"
   end
end

action :remove do 
   execute 'my_script' do 
      command "./#{script_path} stop"
   end
end
```

Also remember you can define methods directly in the provider if they are only useful for that one provider.